# In a list, 1 if it fulfills condition 1, 0 if it fulfills condition 2, ignore it if it does not fulfill both

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this now.

```
gen = ["f", 'M', "female", "Male", "male", "F", "m", "m", "male", "Female", "x"]
```

As their may be different input formats, female may appear as "F", "f", "Female", or "female", and male may appear as "M", "m", "Male", or "male" in the list. How can we turn the list into a new gender list called "gen2" with only 0s and 1s, with 0 representing females, and 1 representing males. If there is any other elements in the list, just assume it as invalid and simply ignore it in the new list?

I tried this:

```
n=0
gen2=[]
for i in gen:
    s=print(gen[n][0]==str.lower('F'))
    if s is True:
        gen2.append(0)
        n=n+1
    elif s is False:
        gen2.append(1)
        n=n+1

print(gen2)
```

and the expected output will be

```
[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
```

Comment: `print` always returns `None`. Don't use it for chains of logic.

Comment: You can make two lists. One of all the possible inputs you can think of that would represent female inputs, and another to do the same but for the male inputs. If you use the variable `input` as your user input, you can do a basic `if input in list:` which will return true or false depending on which list you pick, then else the other condition.

Answer (score 1):

```
gen2=[]
for i in gen:
    if i[0].lower() == "f":
        gen2.append(0)
    else:
        gen2.append(1)

print(gen2)
```

Answer (score 0):

`print` always returns `None`--it's not suitable for use in logic like this. Also, there's no need for `n` and `i`--you already have the element with `i` (probably only use `i` for indices, though--prefer `s`, `x` or `e` to represent an arbitrary element in a list).

You could use a small lookup table that performs the conversions, then filter and translate in a list comprehension:

```
>>> gender_to_binary = dict(m=1, M=1, f=0, F=0)
>>> [gender_to_binary[x[0]] for x in gen if x and x[0] in gender_to_binary]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
```

`if x` protects against empty iterables (there's almost never a need for `foo is True`, just `foo` is sufficient and reads cleanly).

If your logic is that the match must be exact on `"m"`/`"male"`/`"f"`/`"female"` case insensitively, this is more precise:

```
>>> gender_to_binary = dict(m=1, male=1, f=0, female=0)
>>> [gender_to_binary[x.lower()] for x in gen if x.lower() in gender_to_binary]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily answered with this code

```
gen = ["f", 'M', "female", "Male", "male", "F", "m", "m", "male", "Female", "x"]
gen2=[]
for i in gen:
    print(i.lower())
    if i.lower() == 'f' or i.lower() == 'female':
        gen2.append(0)
    elif i.lower() == 'm' or i.lower() == 'male':
        gen2.append(1)
print(gen2)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not the efficient method but you can use two list comprehensions

```
gen = ["f", 'M', "female", "Male", "male", "F", "m", "m", "male", "Female", "x","y"]

a=[0  if x.lower().startswith('f') else 1 if x.lower().startswith('m') else None for x in gen]
[i for i in a if i != None]
```

using `if`, `else if` and `else` in list comprehension. using string methods `lower` and `startswith` and in 2nd list comprehension removing the `None` items.
Output:

```
[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
```